# node Bcrypt compare always returns success

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

always when I try to compare between the newUser.password with profile.password it gives me success even if I put a wrong password

and here is my code

```
    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const router = require('express').Router()
// const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
let User = require('../models/user.model')

 router.route('/login').post(async(req, res) => {
    var newUser = {};
    newUser.email = req.body.email;

    newUser.password = req.body.password;
    console.log(newUser.password)
     User.findOne({ email: newUser.email })
      .then(profile => {
        if (!profile) {
          res.send("User not exist");
```

here it will compare for me the hashed pass with the pass that the client give

```
        }else if(bcrypt.compare(newUser.password, profile.password)){
            res.send("success");
```

here will stop

```
        }
        else if((newUser.password !== profile.password)){
          res.send("wrong");
          }
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Erorr: ' + err))
        
})

router.route('/add').post(async(req, res) => {
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)

    const username = req.body.username
    const email = req.body.email
    const password = hashedPassword
    const firstname = req.body.firstname
    const lastname = req.body.lastname

    const newUser = new User({username, email, password, firstname, lastname})
    
    // const accessToken = jwt.sign(password, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    // res.json({ accessToken: accessToken })

    newUser.save()
    .then(() => res.json('User added!'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Erorr: ' + err))
})

// function authToken(req, res, next){
//     const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']
//     const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]
//     if (token == null ) return res.sendStatus(401)

//     jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, password) => {
//         if (err) return res.sendStatus(403)
//         req.password = password
//         next()
//     })
// }

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Try using `then` with bcrypt.compare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bcrypt.compare` is asynchronous so use `async` and `await` keyword. Try this,

```
newUser.password = req.body.password;
console.log(newUser.password)
 User.findOne({ email: newUser.email })
  //async keyword below
  .then(async profile => {
    if (!profile) {
      res.send("User not exist");

  //await keyword below
}else if(await bcrypt.compare(newUser.password, profile.password)){
        res.send("success");
```

Comment: You are welcome. Upvote and mark this as right answer, so that this might help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using async of compare and hash You should chain with then or async await
Here is short form of your code and run mongodb and node user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
});

run().catch((err) => console.log(err));

async function run() {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();

    const UserModel = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
    const newUser = { email: 'test@test.com', password: 'Alexa123' };
    const hasPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(newUser.password, 10);
    const user = new UserModel({ email: newUser.email, password: hasPassword });
    await user.save();

    const getUser = await UserModel.findOne({ email: 'test@test.com' }).exec();
    console.log(getUser);
    // put password wrong here you will get result as expected
    if (bcrypt.compareSync('Alexa123', getUser.password)) {
        console.log('password matched');
    } else {
        console.log('password is wrong');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx the problem was about await and async and worked now

Answer (score 0):

I have same issues to. But finally solved by change datatype from CHAR to String(im using sequelize

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).